# Why do I keep getting a "no viable alternative at character ´´ " error within my test class?

Tags: apex, unit-test, extension

I´m trying to test my extension:

```
public class CampaignRelatedListExtension
{
    public List<CampaignMember> campaignMembers { get; private set; }
    public CampaignRelatedListExtension(ApexPages.StandardController controller)
    {
        campaignMembers = [
            SELECT Campaign.Name, Description_c FROM CampaignMember
            WHERE ContactId = :controller.getId()

        ];  
}

    public PageReference save() {
    update CampaignMembers;
    return null;
    }
 }
```

with this:

```
@isTest
private class CampaignRelatedListExtensionTest{
    static testMethod void validateCampaignRelatedListExtension(){ 
    Test.StartTest();   

        Account acc = new Account(Name = 'Test Account', Type = 'Prospect');
        insert acc;

        acc = [SELECT Id FROM Account WHERE Name = 'Test Account'];

        Contact c = new Contact(AccountID = acc.Id, FirstName = 'Test', LastName = 'Contact');
        insert c;
        c = [SELECT Id FROM Contact WHERE LastName = 'Contact'];

        Campaign cam = new Campaign(Name = 'Test Campaign');

        insert cam;

        cam = [SELECT Id FROM Campaign WHERE Name = 'Test Campaign'];

        CampaignMember cm = new CampaignMember(CampaignId = cam.Id, ContactId = c.Id, Description__c = 'Note');

        insert cm;

        cm = [SELECT Id FROM CampaignMember WHERE Contact =: c.Id AND Description__c = 'Note' ];



     PageReference prf = controller.save(); 

        system.assertEquals(cm.Description__c = 'Note');
      

 

       test.StopTest();

    }
}
```

...as my extension´s code coverage falls just below 75%.

However, I keep getting this error at `c = [SELECT Id FROM Contact WHERE LastName = 'Contact'];`.

Now I´ve read that this is due to poor formatting, but I´m not seeing any problems in that department.

Comment: Did you copy and paste from somewhere. Remove and retype the quotes

Comment: @Eric, I didn´t, but this was one of the first potential causes Í saw when I googled it, so I´ve tried this solution anyway, but to no avail.

Comment: Just remove the query then. You do not need it anyway as the id will be populated on insert

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A copy and paste of your test class compiles fine (With one small change) on my end so it is most likely an issue with some character in your editor it does not like

**Note** This line in your code does not compile:

```
cm = [SELECT Id FROM CampaignMember WHERE Contact =: c.Id AND Description__c = 'Note' ];
```

As `Contact` is an sObject not an Id. It should be changed to:

```
cm = [SELECT Id FROM CampaignMember WHERE ContactId =: c.Id AND Description__c = 'Note' ];
```

Additionally:

1. There is no need to query the sObjects to get the Id after insert as the variables you are inserting will have the Id automatically updated after the DML
2. Your test class is not testing anything. It is simply an execution script. You should at a minimum be doing some system asserts to assure that what you expected the code to do actually happens.